# How To display block from nth of type 2 in list item jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have ul item with many list item on it, the first list is show and from seconed item is none. I need to show the remain list refer jquery when i click on first list

```
<ul>
   <li>first item</li>
   <li style='display: none'>seconed item</li>
   <li style='display: none'>third item</li>
   <li style='display: none'>fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need jQuery. This can be done in vanilla javascript:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.children[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  for(var i = 1; i < list.children.length; i++) {
    list.children[i].style.display = "list-item";
  }
});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>seconed item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>third item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

In case you want to hide/show the list items when the first item is clicked, you can use a `hide` class:

```js
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.children[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  for(var i = 1; i < list.children.length; i++) {
    list.children[i].classList.toggle("hide");
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>first item</li>
  <li>seconed item</li>
  <li>third item</li>
  <li>fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What happens if the OP has jQuery already loaded on the page? Should he avoid using it just for the sake of "do not need jQuery" argument?

Comment: No. Questions asking for jQuery can be answered to using vanilla javascript, unless the OP explicitly states that they only need jQuery. There are also other answers using jQuery.

Comment: Sure you can. But it's difficult for me to see the advantages of doing this. Even more when the question has in the title jquery and it's tagged using jQuery. Nevertheless, your answer is valid, just wanted to understand what is the motive to avoid using jQuery when it's loaded on the page since I can see none.

Comment: Another user might search for a similar problem on Stack Overflow, land on this question and use one of the given answers. What if this user does not want to use jQuery? This answer will fit them. If they do want to use jQuery, another answer will fit them. That's the point.

Comment: Understood. I thought there could be an advantage in case of vanilla JS, but as you said, it's just for the sake of other possible needs (not expressed in this question). IMO answers should be as objective as possible to the OP's need. But I also think this comment thread is taking too much space =P. Anyway, thanks replying this far, and satisfying my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use jQuery:

```js
$('.click').on('click', function() {
  $(this).siblings().css({
    'display': 'block'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="click">first item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>seconed item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>third item</li>
  <li style='display: none'>fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).siblings()` is very clever! Nice answer ;)

Comment: @a--m Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking to do is pretty easy to do, you just attach a class to it and then with jquery change that class to show your elements:

```js
$("#firstItem").click(function(){
    $(".restItem").css("display","list-item");
});
```

```css
.restItem {
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id="firstItem" >first item</li>
   <li class="restItem">seconed item</li>
   <li class="restItem">third item</li>
   <li class="restItem">fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to hide the list elements and toggle that class for all `li` except the first.

Here an example that toggle the visibility, click multiple times on the first item will hide/show the others:

```js
$('li:first-child').click(() => {
  $('li:not(:first)').toggleClass('hide')
})
```

```css
.hide { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>first item</li>
  <li class='hide'>seconed item</li>
  <li class='hide'>third item</li>
  <li class='hide'>fourth item</li>
</ul>
```